# When I call funcion cidades Notice: Undefined property: Dados::$cidades

Tags: php

file capitais.php

```
   <?php
/*Capitais*/
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('dados.php');
$dados = new Dados;
$estado = $dados->_estado;
$capitais = $dados->_capitais;
for($i=1;$i<count($estado);$i++){
    echo $estado["$i"].' : '.array_search($capitais["$i"],$dados->cidades["$i"]).'<br />';
}
?>
```

file dados.php

```
    <?php

class Dados{
        public $_estado = array("Selecione","AC","AL","AM","AP","BA");
        public $_capitais = array("Selecione Primeiro o Estado","RIO BRANCO","MACEIO","MANAUS","MACAPA","SALVADOR");
        public function cidades($estado){
            switch($estado){
                case "1":
                    return array("Selecione","RIO BRANCO","RODRIGUES ALVES","SANTA ROSA","SENA MADUREIRA","SENADOR GUIOMARD","TARAUACA","XAPURI");
                break;
                case "2":
                    return array("Selecione","MACEIO","MAJOR ISIDORO","MAR VERMELHO","MARAGOGI","MARAVILHA","MARECHAL DEODORO","MARIBONDO");
                break;
                case "3":
                    return array("Selecione","MANAQUIRI","MANAUS","MANICORE","MARAA","MAUES","NHAMUNDA","NOVA OLINDA DO NORTE","NOVO AIRAO","NOVO ARIPUANA","PARINTINS","PAUINI","URUCURITUBA");
                break;
                case "4":
                    return array("Selecione","AMAPA","CALCOENE","MACAPA");
                break;
                case "5":
                    return array("Selecione","RUY BARBOSA","SALINAS DA MARGARIDA","SALVADOR","SANTA BARBARA");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Notice: Undefined property: Dados::$cidades in capitais.php on line 14

Warning: array_search() [function.array-search]: Wrong datatype for second argument in

Comment: Pass the $i parameter to cidades() function. You're treating it as an array

Comment: I confused with the parameter array. Thank you solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dados->cidades["$i"]
```

should be

```
$dados->cidades("$i")
```

Answer (score 0):

cicades isn't a property of the Dados class, it's a method, so it needs to be called as

```
$dados->cidades();
```

passing in the appropriate $estado argument

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $estado["$i"].' : '.array_search($capitais["$i"],$dados->cidades["$i"]).'<br />';
```

should be

```
echo $estado["$i"].' : '.array_search($capitais["$i"],$dados->cidades("$i")).'<br />';
```

as cidades is a function, not an array property.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dados->cidades["$i"]) should be $dados->cidades($i))
```